# Matrix Multiplication Algebra -Equality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, matrix-equations

First time post.
I am looking at a question that should seem very simple. It is stated as follows:

Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices.

Show that if $AB = A$ and $BA=B$

then $A^2=A$ and $B^2=B$.

I have tried a few different approaches.
1)
If $A=AB$ then 
$$A^2=(AB)^2$$
$$A^2=(AB)(AB)$$
$$A^2=A(BA)A $$
$$A^2=ABA$$
But I didnt get anywhere and I am not sure if I can use associativity in line 3.

2)
Then I thought what about if we approached it like somewhat like this
$$(A+B)^2=A^2+AB+BA+B^2$$

Then the $AB=A$ and $BA=B$ can be used so
$$(A+B)^2=A^2+A+B+B^2$$
then maybe you can set $A^2+A$ to zero (maybe??) and $B+B^2$ to zero (maybe??). But this doesnt give me something nice so what about if we tried expanding the expression
$$(A-B)^2=A^2+AB-BA+B^2$$
$$(A-B)^2=A^2+A-B+B^2$$
Then we would be able to set $A^2+A$ to zero (maybe??) and $-B+B^2$ to zero (maybe??). Then at least part of it would make sense. i.e. 
$$-B+B^2=0$$
$$B^2=B$$

Would really appreciate some help if possible.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Nice first question!

Comment: To answer your question in 1), yes you can apply associativity as it is. In fact, you are very close to the answer. From $A^2 = ABA$ replace $BA=B$ to get $A^2=AB$ and so $A^2=A$.

Comment: Not sure what ettiquette is to say thanks, maybe an upvote or something. just wanted to say thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $AB=A$ and $BA=B$.Then $A^2=AA=(AB)A=A(BA)=AB=A$. And $B^2=BB=(BA)B=B(AB)=BA=B$ and done.

Comment: Not sure what ettiquette is to say thanks, maybe an upvote or something. just wanted to say thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
A^2=\color{red}{A}A=\color{red}{AB}A 
=A\color{blue}{BA}=A\color{blue}{B}=A.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Not sure what ettiquette is to say thanks, maybe an upvote or something. just wanted to say thank you very much!